# Registering LocationListener required?

Tags: java, android, location

In my application, I only need to get a `Location` when a certain button is clicked. Do I still need to register a `LocationListener`, or can I just use something this?

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location position = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you need the location for.  The LastKnown Location may be from 10 minutes ago.  Is that sufficiently good for your purpose?  Or do you need the GPS to turn on right now, because my understanding is that call will not turn on the GPS.

Comment: So using `LocationListener.onLocationChanged(...)` will always show the current location via Wi-Fi, GPS, network provider?

Comment: It will turn on whichever location provider you ask it to and return you the first location "fix" it gets after that in the onLocationChanged callback.

Comment: Would it help to save battery life if I were to unregister the listener in the `onPause()`?

Comment: 100% it would.  Heck, if ou did not think they would move much between onResume and when you needed the location, you can unregister after you get the first Location fix to save battery life.  GPS is a serious battery hog.

Comment: Ok thanks! But if I don't need to know if the location changed and update based on that, I need to be able to grab the current location in a method. In a method, I need to grab the current location and do some processing with that. How would using LocationListener help if it will only give me information when the location is changed, which might not happen?

Comment: Well, it "changes" the first time because it goes from no location to some location when it gets the first fix.  So, you should always get a first location.  then if they are not moving you won't get any more updates.  So, you need to store the location you received somewhere.